# sending push notification firebase react-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was working on a project using Firebase cloud messaging react. I was sending this to my server, but it doesn't work. Surely I have tried, but I don't know what's wrong again.

Below is the code.
Here it sends a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request to Firebase, and it should send a notification to the user.

```
async function sendNotification(id, userMessage) {
    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `key=${code}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    const message = {
        'to': `${id}`,
        'content_available': true,
        'apns_priority': 5,
        'notification': {
        body: `${userMessage}`
    },
    const url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
    //console.log(code)

    await axios.post(url, message, {
        headers: headers
    })
}
const sendMessageToServer = async (e) => {
    //e.preventDefault();
    toggle()
    const docRe = doc(database, "help", mailer);
    const data = {
        email: user.email,
        user: newMessage,
    }
    //console.log(data, 'not clear')
    setNewMessage('')
    //console.log(data, newMessage, 'cleared')
    setShow(false)
    if(newMessage === '') {

    }
    else {
        const docRef = doc(database, "users", mailer);
        await updateDoc(docRe, {
            msg: arrayUnion(data)
        })
        .then(() => {
            async function p() {
                const id = await getDoc(docRef)
                //console.log(id.data())
                sendNotification(id.data().notice, `Admin : ${data.user}`)
            }
            p()
        })
    }
```

Sometimes it sends to my localhost because I tested there, but it doesn't work on my [Netlify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlify) app. Secondly, I noticed that it keeps generating the same token for each user, but that's not the issue, but if you can help in both I would be grateful.

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    async function callToken() {
        await getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: process.env.NOTIFICATION})
        .then((code) => {
            //console.log(code)

            async function docRef() {
                const dc = doc(database, "users", auth.currentUser.email);
                await updateDoc(dc, {
                    notice: code
                });
            }
            docRef()
        })
    }

    async function requestPermission() {
        await Notification.requestPermission()
        .then((permission) => {
            if (permission === 'granted') {
                console.log('Notification permission granted.')
                callToken()
            }
        })
    }

    const goTo = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (data) => {

            if(!data) {
                goTo('/login')
            }
            else {
                currentBalance();

                requestPermission()
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Please know I imported all required modules.

Comment: Is that the actual code? It looks suspicious near "`await axios.post(url`"? Is that syntactically correct?

Comment: Is [ASI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons) supposed work near "`console.log('Notification permission granted.')`"?

Comment: Hello thanks for replying, the request permission code, gives a prompt to user to allow notifications if user grants the request it moves to CallToken function which saves the id gotten from Firebase

Comment: I don't know what's actually wrong I'm just tired